# Tables from H2DB file doesn't appear in IDEA, but shows in H2 console

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

I have some simple Spring Boot project with H2db file with location ./dbs/database.mv.db ( ./ from my project's dir). application.properties is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./dbs/database;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

So, Spring Boot App got it and can manipulate with table in it, stores data in DB file. Console by localhost:8080/h2 show it too. But I have problem with IDEA: IDEA got connection only by absolute name (Embedded source with url jdbc:h2:~/Documents/projects/java/seccomp/dbs/database;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE). But in this case IDEA show me no tables at all. I'm confused, probably App creates some table in target directory? No, if I have removed my mv.db file from .dbs/ it will create again after data manipulation from Application.

Why Application and H2 Console show me tables, but IDEA doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

With the `./dbs/database;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` you are specifying the path to a database file which is resolved relative to the corrent working direcrory where you program is run. With the `~/Documents/projects/java/seccomp/dbs/database` - you are specifying it relatively you user home. Make sure you are actually **specifying the same path** in these both cases.